# Translating a sentence in a quantified statement

Tags: logic

How would you write the following proposition as a quantified statement?

> "There are no birds that belong to anyone but me"

Assume the following boolean functions:

- $B(x)$ (Is $x$ a bird?),
- $O(x)$ (Is $x$ an ostrich?),
- $T(x)$ (Is $x$ is at least 9 feel tall?),
- $I(x)$ (Do I have $x$, i.e., does $x$ belong to me?),
- $L(x, y)$ (Does $x$ belong to $y$?).

Write as a quantified statement: "There are no birds that belong to anyone but me".

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, so what does that sentence even mean? Does it mean that "All birds belong to me"?

Comment: Can you write the statement "there are no birds" first?

Comment: No but you are able to write there are no birds that belong to me

Comment: Then, second, write a formula "x belongs to anyone but me". Hint: of the predicates listed, you'll only need $I(x)$ and $L(x, y)$. It's a weird phrase, so I'm not surprised that you're unsure how to proceed. @HowDoIMath I am a native English speaker and I had to think about what it might mean  – probably no one has ever actually said this :)

Comment: Yeah thats the part im stuck on  


I have: For all x, such that B(x), ~I(x) and...

Comment: Save the negation for last. First try: "there is a bird that belongs to anyone but me"; then negate *that*.

Comment: So i would also have to create another variable for "anyone"?
I could write there exists a bird x such that x doesnt belong to me, but thats not the same as "anyone but me".

Comment: That's right: the *bird* is represented by one variable, the *someone* in "anyone but you" by another.

Comment: Did you figure it out?